# Redirect root domain only, but keep some subdomains pointer to original root domain

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, subdomain

I have the following config:

```
Type    Name    Value

A       @       192.0.2.123
A       www     192.0.2.111
CNAME   test    @
CNAME   mail    @
```

Is it possible to temporary redirect the root domain to the `www` subdomain, so that when I type in the browser `example.com`, I will be redirected to `www.example.com`'s `192.0.2.111` address. But when I type `test.example.com` or `mail.example.com` I will be get the `192.0.2.123` address?

My registrar is GoDaddy. I tried using the forwarding feature from GoDaddy's DNS management page, but it did not work at all and similar questions to this one had it done in `htaccess` on the server side.

Comment: DNS only tells a client what IP address it can find a server on. That server must also send a coherent response, by whatever protocol you wish (e.g. HTTP). That's why you have to edit your web server configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the web server part. I can't have the 123.123.123.123 webserver redirect clients to 111.111.111.111 since it often times the server will be down - i.e. its meant to be private. That is why need to have it redirected by default to 111.111.111.111.

Comment: You should have some other web server do it, then. Of course it doesn't make any sense that the server would be down often.

Comment: Can i simply reverse it? Turn `test` and `email` into `A` records that point to `123.123.123.123` and change the `root`/`@` to point to `111.111.111.111`? Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking at it from this perspective:

DNS is designed to be more static and aid in the translation of domains to IPs.

Web servers are designed to deliver web content and handle the intricacies of such.  This includes URL rewriting and redirections and such.

That being said, your DNS entries should be as simple as pointing to what "box" you want people to reach when they use a specific domain.

In your specific case, I wonder if the `192.0.2.123` is even hosting a web server.  If it only serves mail protocols or other things, it wouldn't be efficient to install a web server and configure it with the sole purpose of redirecting requests, but it is a possible solution.  However, it is extremely common to have to handle the whole `www.example.com` vs. `example.com` redirection, but that is done using URL rewriting.

In this case, I would recommend setting the root domain and the `www` to the web server IP `192.0.2.111` and eliminate the `CNAME` records and instead change them to A records and point them to `192.0.2.123`.

On another note, if your `mail` server handles receiving mail for your domain, you may need to set up an `MX` record for your root domain to point to `192.0.2.123`.  This will work (and is extremely common) because e-mail DNS lookups specifically look for `MX` records, vs `A` records.